# 'use strict' on npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there any reason why I should consider not using 'use strict' in [a node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitwise) published via npm? Is it 'safe' to do that if I want others to be able to use it?

EDIT: I asked this question explicitly to find out, if it can make the module useless/broken for anybody who wants to install it via npm.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417381/in-node-js-how-the-use-strict-statement-is-interpreted

Comment: Is it really a duplicate? I was explicitly asking for any compatibility reasons when I publish a module via npm.

Comment: Well read how and why you can/should use it and what does it mean. Then you will simply understand where to and not to use it. It's very simple, you just need to read it.

Comment: I see you won't do any effort, but I can tell you that there is an accepted answer (with 35 score) that has **exactly** what you're searching for! :)

Comment: AFAIK 'use strict' is scoped to your module, (or even specific functions, if you like). I shouldn't need to know/care if you used 'use strict' in order to use your module, as long as your module works.

Comment: IF this were a dupliclate, surely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it would be a better candidate. (I do not think this is a duplicate of either, though, knowing the information from either should be enough to answer the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'use strict';` enforces a set of rules on your code. If ran in an environment that doesn't support `'use strict';`, it is simply ignored, no harm done.

It will only apply to your code, assuming it is not concatenated with anyone else's code (unless you're using it inside of a function rather than outside, in which case it would only affect that function, even if concatenated.)

Therefore, Yes, it is safe to use `'use strict';` in a piece of code without fear of it causing problems for other people using your code. I would even go as far as saying it is recommended.