# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$__firebase' in undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, openshift

I'm getting an error importing the Firebase npm module with an app hosted by OpenShift.

The following line

```
firebase = require('firebase/app'),
```

produces the following output in the log file

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$__firebase' in undefined at /var/lib/openshift/57408de67628e1e65b00006a/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:19:449
> at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/57408de67628e1e65b00006a/approot/runtime/repo/node_modules/firebase/app-node.js:19:617)
> at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
> at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/57408de67628e1e65b00006a/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js:8:18)
> at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
> at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
> at /var/lib/openshift/57408de67628e1e65b00006a/app-root/runtime/repo/app.js:12:20
> ```

The strange thing is that if I execute

```
$ node app.js
```

there is no error and the app runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the --use-strict option in package.json, if you are using the cartridge with start.js and cluster.

See this stackoverflow q&a for more details on strict mode: [in-node-js-how-the-use-strict-statement-is-interpreted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417381/in-node-js-how-the-use-strict-statement-is-interpreted)

Hope it helps!

Comment: That seems to work. Could you edit your answer to explain why it works for myself and future readers? Cheers.