# In Node, this inside function equals undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node, how come I get undefined in this example ?

Since I am not using strict mode, this should be accessible from inside a function and equal to the Global object.

```
this.foo = "bar";

function fun () {
    console.log(this.foo);
}

fun(); // undefined
```

Comment: @Mohammad, on Node it does

Comment: The global object is obtained using `global`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fragment about `"use strict"` mode in MDN.

> First, the value passed as `this` to a function in strict mode is not forced into being an object (a.k.a. "boxed"). For a normal function, `this` is always an object: either the provided object if called with an object-valued `this`; the value, boxed, if called with a Boolean, string, or number `this`; or the global object if called with an undefined or null `this`...  for a strict mode function, the specified `this` is not boxed into an object, and if unspecified, `this` will be undefined:

For a best explanation and examples, see the reference:
["Securing" JavaScript (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript)

Also see this post in stackoverflow: [In node.js, how the 'use strict' statement is interpreted?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417571/2247494)

Comment: No, node.js does not enable strict mode by itself. OP states he does not `"use strict"`.

Comment: You are right @Bergi, I am running my `npm` scripts with `node --use_strict` flag.